# how to convert a blob string to file using pyspark

Tags: file, dataframe, pyspark, blob, azure-eventhub

I have a pyspark notebook where I am reading azure event-hub messages and one of the fields is a string that is a blob field, a file, from the oracle database.
I am trying to convert the string to file, binary, then write to blob storage in azure, but I can't do that.
How do I convert the string to a file?

```
  ds.selectExpr("cast (body as string) as body") \
    .select(from_json("body", schema).alias("data")) \
    .select("data.*") \
    .withColumn('test1', base64(col("BINR_ANX"))) \
    .withColumn('test2', unbase64(col("BINR_ANX")))
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to read messages from Azure Event Hub and extract a field of a json message to store it to Azure Blob Storage in PySpark notebook.

As I known, if it's not necessary in PySpark, the simple solution is to use Azure Stream Stream Analytics to create a job with [EventHub as input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-inputs) and [Blob Storage as output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-outputs#blob-storage-and-azure-data-lake-gen2) and without any code to write an expression to [parse JSON data in Query Language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-parsing-json?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstream-analytics%2FTOC.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json) to extract the data you want for realizing your needs. Please refer to the offical tutorial [`Quickstart: Create a Stream Analytics job by using the Azure portal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-quick-create-portal) to know how to do.

Otherwise, if you have to do that in PySpark notebook, you need to follow the steps below to try to do.

1. Follow the offical tutorial [`Send events to or receive events from Event Hubs using Python`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-python-get-started-send) to install Python EventHub SDK to receive messages and extract the data of the field you want by [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).
2. Follow the offical tutorial [`Quickstart: Upload, download, and list blobs with Python`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python) to install Azure Blob Storage SDK for Python to store the data to Azure Blob.
3. Make the two steps above within a loop for receiving messages from EventHub continously.

The solution above is a normal way in Python. I don't know the PySpark notebook you used in what Azure service like Azure Databricks or others you owned not on Azure cloud. So if your pyspark notebook is in Azure Databricks, there is not direct way to access Azure Event Hub, but Azure Blob Storage as a data source supported by Azure Databricks, you can refer to the offical document [`Data Sources > Azure Blob Storage`](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html) to easily store data into blob without Python Blob Storage SDK.

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

I was able to solve the problem and write the file, but it is not possible to send the full message through the event hub, because the string with the file is too long.
I solved the problem by processing a dataframe where I converted the string and file and saved it to azure blob storage.

def convert_to_file(row):
  file_decode = base64.decodebytes(str(row.column_name).encode())
  filename = "/dbfs/mnt/file.xxx"
    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
        f.write(file_decode)

ds.writeStream.foreach(convert_to_file).start()

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem and write the file, but it is not possible to send the full message through the event hub, because the string with the file is too long.
I solved the problem by processing a dataframe where I converted the string and file and saved it to azure blob storage.

```
def convert_to_file(row):
  file_decode = base64.decodebytes(str(row.column_name).encode())
  filename = "/dbfs/mnt/file.xxx"
    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
        f.write(file_decode)

ds.writeStream.foreach(convert_to_file).start()
```